# Pasar variables por URL

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, url

Estoy tratando de pasar variables por url con php pero hay un momento en el que pierdo unos datos y no se en que parte del código estoy fallando para que esto me suceda.

```
<a href="mostrar_notarias.php?documento_seleccionado=<?php echo $documento_seleccionado; ?>&nombre=<?php echo $nombre; ?>">Continuar</a></button>
```

aqui envio datos a la siguiente pagina en la cual desde la BD saco otros datos para que el usuario pueda seleccionar. pero al momneto de presionar el boton continuar ya pierdo los datos anteriores como son : el documento seleccionado y el nombre.

```
 echo '<td><a href="mostrar_horas.php?documento_seleccionado=' . $fila['id'] . '&nombre=' . $fila['nombre'] . '&notaria_seleccionada=' . $fila['id'] . '" class="btn btn-outline-warning"><h6>Continuar</h6></a></td>';
```

veo que en esta ultima URL no llamo a documento seleccionado ni a nombre pero no se como llamarlos para que se mantengan almacenados en la URL

```
<?php

//TRAIGO LOS DATOS DESDE EL URL Y LOS COLOCO DENTRO DE VARIABLES
if (isset($_GET['documento_seleccionado']) && isset($_GET['nombre'])) {
  $documento_seleccionado = $_GET['documento_seleccionado'];
  $nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
}
?>

<?php

// Conecta a la base de datos
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=notaria', 'root', '');

// Recoge el ID del documento seleccionado del formulario
$id = $_GET['notaria_seleccionada'];

// Ejecuta una consulta para obtener los datos del documento seleccionado
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM notarias WHERE id = :id');
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$documento = $stmt->fetch();


?>
```

esto tengo en la segunda pagina para traer los datos de la pagina anterior en la URL

Comment: puedes debugear que parametros estas  mandando por el metodo GET con un print_r($_GET);

Comment: Un consejo: donde pones "TRAIGO LOS DATOS DESDE EL URL Y LOS COLOCO DENTRO DE VARIABLES" deberías eliminar esas asignaciones y trabajar siempre con los datos originales. Eso te permitirá saber en todo momento la procedencia de los datos sin lugar a dudas. Además, deberías generar un error HTTP 422 (Unprocessable Entity) y finalizar la ejecución si alguno de los parámetros falta y es obligatorio.

Comment: Además, como te indica @DonaldoManzano, deberías depurar el HTML generado en el enlace y compartirlo en la pregunta. Eso podría dar una pista acerca de si el problema está en variables no definidas o bien haber procesado incorrectamente los datos (como indico en mi respuesta). Además, deberías mirar el registro de error del servidor para observar si te están apareciendo advertencias de PHP que no se estén mostrando en la página (configuración por defecto para producción, pero lo contrario es lo deseado para desarrollo).

Comment: pude pasar los datos realizando esto, pero de igual forma utilizare las sugerencias que me dieron para mejorar mi codigo ` echo '<td><a href="mostrar_horas.php?documento_seleccionado='.$documento_seleccionado .'&nombre='.$nombre . '&nombrenot=' . $fila['nombre'] . '&notaria_seleccionada=' . $fila['id'] . '&direccion='. $fila['direccion'] . '&comuna='. $fila['comuna'] .'" class="btn btn-outline-warning"><h6>Continuar</h6></a></td>';`

Comment: y tome los datos de la pagina siguiente de esta forma ``` <?php

//TRAIGO LOS DATOS DESDE EL URL Y LOS COLOCO DENTRO DE VARIABLES
if (isset($_GET['documento_seleccionado']) && isset($_GET['nombre'])) {
  $documento_seleccionado = $_GET['documento_seleccionado'];
  $nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
  $notaria_seleccionada = $_GET['notaria_seleccionada'];
  $nombrenot = $_GET['nombrenot'];
  $direccion = $_GET['direccion'];
  $comuna = $_GET['comuna'];
}


// Conecta a la base de datos
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=notaria', 'root', '');

?>  ```

Answer (score 2):

Los datos que estás enviando no están correctamente escapados.

En vez de usar:

```
<a href="mostrar_notarias.php?documento_seleccionado=<?php echo $documento_seleccionado; ?>&nombre=<?php echo $nombre; ?>">Continuar</a>
```

Deberías usar:

```
<a href="mostrar_notarias.php?documento_seleccionado=<?= urlencode($documento_seleccionado) ?>&amp;nombre=<?= urlencode($nombre) ?>">Continuar</a>
```

Fíjate en los siguientes cambios:

- Cambio `<?php echo ...; ?>` por `<?= ... ?>`.
- Uso [`urlencode()`](https://php.net/urlencode) para escapar caracteres que puedan romper la cadena enviada.
- He cambiado `&` por `&amp;` porque cuando se introducen URLs separadas por `&` en HTML hay que escapar el carácter y sustituirlo por `&amp;`.

Aunque deberías usar este otro método usando [`http_build_query()`](https://php.net/http_build_query):

```php
<a href="mostrar_notarias.php?<?= http_build_query([
    'documento_seleccionado' => $documento_seleccionado,
    'nombre' => $nombre,
], '', '&amp;') ?>">Continuar</a>
```

En el segundo ejemplo quedaría así:

```php
<td>
    <a href="mostrar_horas.php?<?= http_build_query([
        'documento_seleccionado' => $fila['id'],
        'nombre' => $fila['nombre'],
        'notaria_seleccionada' => $fila['id'],
    ], '', '&amp;') ?>" class="btn btn-outline-warning">
        <h6>Continuar</h6>
    </a>
</td>
```

He reproducido tu problema en el siguiente repositorio de Github, donde podrás comprobar que funciona correctamente:

- [image: Gitpod Ready-to-Code] https://github.com/ojgarciab/584996-stackoverflow-es

Además, puedes probar el código en línea usando los servicios de Gitpod:

- https://gitpod.io/#https://github.com/ojgarciab/584996-stackoverflow-es

Comment: gracias seguiré tu consejo para mejorar mi código

Comment: Hola @AndrésGonzález , por favor, lee y atiende los comentarios que te hemos dejado en tu pregunta. Aún quedan dudas acerca del origen real del problema.

Comment: en el segundo ejemplo que me enviaste <td>
    <a href="mostrar_horas.php?<?= http_build_query([
        'documento_seleccionado' => $fila['id'],
        'nombre' => $fila['nombre'],
        'notaria_seleccionada' => $fila['id'],
    ], '', '&amp;') ?>" class="btn btn-outline-warning">
        <h6>Continuar</h6>
    </a>
</td> 
me da error al ingresarlo ya que esta en php el resto del codigo y las comillas dan problemas y al cambiarlas igualmente me da error

Comment: Quizá no estás agregando el código del segundo ejemplo como HTML (fuera de las etiquetas PHP). Te recomiendo no usar construcciones del tipo `echo "<p>código HTML con $variable</p>";`, si no usar en su lugar `<p>código HTML con <?= htmlspecialchars($variable) ?></p>`. El motor de coloreado de stackoverflow no es muy bueno, por eso falla al visualizarlo, pero el de github es mejor y no falla al colorear el código: https://github.com/ojgarciab/584996-stackoverflow-es/blob/master/public/index.php

Answer (score 1):

La mezcla de contenido HTML / PHP abriendo y cerrando bloques produce un código verdaderamente horrible y difícil de analizar o de depurar.

Para casos como el tuyo, puede ser interesante el uso de [`printf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.printf.php) o de [`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php). Funcionan igual, con la diferencia de que con la primera imprimes in situ, y con la segunda almacenas el contenido en variables, por ejemplo si estás concatenando o creando un array o un objeto.

Así en lugar de esto:

```
<a href="mostrar_notarias.php?documento_seleccionado=<?php echo $documento_seleccionado; ?>&nombre=<?php echo $nombre; ?>">Continuar</a></button>
```

Tendríamos:

```
$query = array(
                'documento_seleccionado'=>$documento_seleccionado,
                'nombre'=>$nombre
              );

printf('<button>
          <a href="mostrar_notarias.php?%s">Continuar</a>
        </button>',
        http_build_query($query));
```

He agregado la etiqueta `<button>` de apertura, la cual no aparece.

Y en lugar de:

```
echo '<td><a href="mostrar_horas.php?documento_seleccionado=' . $fila['id'] . '&nombre=' . $fila['nombre'] . '&notaria_seleccionada=' . $fila['id'] . '" class="btn btn-outline-warning"><h6>Continuar</h6></a></td>';
```

Tendríamos:

```
$query = array(
                'documento_seleccionado'=>$fila['id'],
                'nombre'=>$fila['nombre'],
                'notaria_seleccionada'=>$fila['id']
              );

printf('<td>
         <a href="mostrar_horas.php?%s" class="btn btn-outline-warning"><h6>Continuar</h6></a>
        </td>',
        http_build_query($query));
```

Como vez, tanto `printf()` como `sprintf()` funcionan poniendo marcadores donde va cada dato, y al final pasas los datos en la posición en que deban ir.

En cuanto a tu código PHP, podemos darle claridad usando el operador de fusión de null (PHP 7 o superior) o bien operadores ternarios en su defecto.

```
<?php

    $doc = $_GET['documento_seleccionado'] ?? NULL;
    $nombre = $_GET['nombre'] ?? NULL;
    $id = $_GET['notaria_seleccionada'] ?? NULL;

    if ($doc && $nombre && $id) {
    
        // Conecta a la base de datos
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=notaria', 'root', '');
        
        // Recoge el ID del documento seleccionado del formulario
        
        // Ejecuta una consulta para obtener los datos del documento seleccionado
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM notarias WHERE id = :id');
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $documento = $stmt->fetch();      
    }

?>
```

Es un código más limpio. Te aconsejo que evites el uso de variables con nombres kilométricos. Tal es el caso de `$documento_seleccionado`, con nombrarla `$doc` se salva la comprensión del código y se gana mucho en legibilidad. Le puedes llamar `$pepitoDeLosPalotesYMasCosas` o lo que quieras, pero demasiada verbosidad innecesaria hace que el código sea infumable muchas veces.